# Tokbox Api session recording with ios sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, opentok, tokbox

We have developed one app which include video conferencing using tokbox api. We want to record all video conference and saving it on server for future references from device.

We have developed sample app using following [link](http://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/ios/)

Can any one knows how to record this conference?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Currently archiving with OpenTok is in beta, you can signup [here](http://tokbox.com/platform#archiving). Knowing TokBox, you should be able to get an invite rather quickly.